# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in submitting equation format from form textarea (ckeditor)

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

Hi there I am submitting a equation from ckeditor and geting MethodNotAllowedException though my form has method type post and route also post.

Here is my view.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('set-question')}}" id="submit_form" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="col-md126 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
         <label class="control-label">Question</label>
         <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px;">Question is required</p>
         <textarea name="question" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">            
        </div>     
      </form>
```

[image]
If I type this or some other equation only then other problem arise. I have saved by typing other format even with bengali language that was good. Bellow is my route and then the typography I was able to save in db via this route and view.

```
Route::post('add-question','Admins\ExamController@addQuestion')->name('set-question');
```

The successful tries.
[image]
But after the highlighted equation or format i got MethodNotAllowedHttpException.
Please suggest me what I'm missing.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your ExamController and function addQuestion.

Comment: I have that. I think that doesn't matter. The main problem is mismatching the route type and on view form action. That's why MethodNotAllowedException arise. I just wanted to know why it's  happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your cache. Because i faced sometime this type of problem and after clean my cache it will be fine.
One thing you can try with name route like: name('set.question)

Comment: I already tried that. And I used named route please look at form. There is action="{{route("set-question")}}.